# Scheduling meetings with no end date

Tags: permissions, exchange-2007, outlook-2007

In Outlook 2007 & Exchange 2007 we have an end user that needs to schedule a recurring meeting with no end date.  When she tries this, she gets a permission denied error.  When I try it (as Domain Admin), it works.

This is the exact error:

- Your meeting request was declined.
- It did not specify an end date. The end date must be before 12/13/2012.

The only 2 permission sets we have on the calendar are Default:Author and Anonymous:None.

I am guessing that the solution to this lies somewhere within a Exchange Power Shell cmdlet, but I am not sure.

Does anyone know how to fix this so that she can use the "no end date" feature?

Comment: Can you schedule any recurring meetings at all?  This is usually disabled for a reason.  They tend to break things.

Comment: She can schedule meetings until the end of 2012.

Comment: And she need to sceudule past the end of the world?  ;)

Answer (score 1):

She might be restricted by the so called `BookingWindowInDays` attribute, which specifies the maximum number of days into the future, that meetings can be booked:

[image]

To override this attribute, update her mailbox calendar (and the calendars of all resource mailboxes she needs to book) with the `EnforceSchedulingHorizon` property set to `false`, like this:

`Set-MailboxCalendarSettings -Identity "user" -EnforceSchedulingHorizon $false`